# source from a text file in an expect file doesn't work

Tags: linux, expect

I have a .sh file and a .exp file and they both have source from other text file that has their variables values in it. when I run the .sh file it will execute the .exp file but it seems like when it gets to that line it can't read the value from the source file properly. I was wondering if I had done it right.

The .sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
source ../common/labinfo/qcow_var.txt

cd $WORKSPACE/qcow_vnf

echo -e "** Starting qcow_vnf Installation **\n** Checking the connectivity     to Host-1...**\n"
../common/isup_addr.sh "$HOSTIP_1" 1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
exit 1
fi

echo -e "** Checking the connectivity to Host-2...**\n"
../common/isup_addr.sh "$HOSTIP_2" 1
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
exit 1
fi 

create_vm.exp "$HOSTIP_1" "$HOSTUSER" "$HOSTPASS" "$VMNAME_1"
```

The .exp file

```
#!/opt/tools/unsupported/expect-5.39/bin/expect
source ../common/labinfo/qcow_var.txt

set HOST [ lindex $argv 0 ]
set USER [ lindex $argv 1 ]
set PASSWORD [ lindex $argv 2 ]
set VMNAME [ lindex $argv 3 ]

echo -e "** Creation of $VMNAME on $HOST begins... **\n"
spawn ssh -l $USER $HOST
expect_after eof {exit 0}
set timeout 10

expect "(yes/no)?" { send "yes\r" }
expect "password:" { send "$PASSWORD\r" }

expect "~]#" { send "date\r" }
set timeout 1200
......(etc)
```

And the .txt file

```
HOSTIP_1=172.28.152.240
HOSTIP_2=172.28.152.241
HOSTUSER="root"
....(and the rest of the variables)
```

Comment: expect is an extension of Tcl, and Tcl does not use the `variable=value` syntax. You cannot use the same config file for both languages (shell and expect) without more parsing code to translate the shell syntax to Tcl.

Answer (score 0):

I found out after I posted my question. I'm quite new to this. The issue is that the source doesn't work like that with expect also I used echo in expect that is also wrong. I fixed my problems and it's working fine now.